# Visualforce User LastModifiedBy Outputfield

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I'm going to post this here even though I already have a workaround, but this is definitely a Salesforce Visualforce bug.

When adding an `<apex:outputField>` for the `LastModifiedById` field for the User record on a `Visualforce Page`. the page crashes with the following error:

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: User.LastModifiedBy**

It can be easily reproduced by creating a simple VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="testusercontroller">
    <apex:outputField value="{!me.LastmodifiedById}"/>
</apex:page>
```

And a simple controller

```
public with sharing class testusercontroller {
    public User getMe(){
        return [select CreatedById, LastmodifiedById from User where Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
    }
}
```

If you change the `<apex:outputField>` to display the `CreatedById` field, everything works fine. Only `LastModifiedById` crashes.

---

ANSWER

The workaround is to change the query to include LastModifedBy.Id and LastModifedBy.Name like this:

```
 public with sharing class testusercontroller {
     public User getMe(){
      return [select CreatedById, LastmodifiedBy.Id, LastmodifiedBy.Name from User where Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
     }
   }
```

Hopefully this helps others as I didn't find any reference to this anywhere.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SFSE! Please take a brief moment to visit the [help] and read [ask] and [answer]. If you want to post an ask-and-answer combo, the answer portion should be a separate answer post (below).

Comment: @alex-sartogo Is your query return value

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more because of the nature of outputfield. For reference fields (relationship fields), outputfield generates a link wherein the text is the record name and link points to record details page. So, by nature it needs both name and id of the linked record. I believe this is what is causing the error, which gets taken care of when you specifically add those additional fields in your query.

Can't say a bug, but error message may be modified for better problem description.